# "Show In Finder" won't open a new finder window

Tags: macos, mac, finder

The "Show In Finder" action isn't working on Mac OS X Mountain Lion. The problem has just started to occur all the time, before it was a bit sporadic, but now it happens all the time.

Things that don't work:

- In the chrome Downloads page clicking any of the "Show in Finder" links.
- Right clicking a file in XCode and choosing "Show in Finder"

Things that work:

- `open .` in terminal
- `command-n` after command tabbing to Finder.

Things I've tried to fix the issue:

- `Opt - Right Click` finder in the dock and relauching
- Restarting my computer

Anybody ever experienced this issue?

Comment: Experienced it... but no idea how I solved it other than possibly through OS updates. Command-clicking a Dock icon will probably not work as well?

Comment: @DanielBeck Command-clicking a dock icon does work

Comment: Just wondering. Do you use TotalFinder? This might be related.

Comment: @Darwin nope. I don't use total finder.

Comment: I've seen it happen as well. Could it be that you're using Dropbox?

Comment: Have you used PathFinder?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is a bug introduced by Apple in 10.8.2.

Workaround: when it happens, in Terminal run the following:

```
sudo killall -KILL appleeventsd
```

Alternatively, use Activity Monitor to kill *appleeventsd*. [More information](http://d43.me/blog/1511/show-in-finder-not-working-in-mountain-lion) on the issue.

Comment: This didn't work for me on 10.8.2.

Comment: Didn't work for me either.

Comment: Worked on 10.8.2. Would have accepted sooner, but stopped happening after I posted the question -- one day I will find Murphy and slap him with a piece of peanut butter toast. Peanut butter side up!

Comment: Terminating appleeventsd works for me as well. It also fixes an issue where Archive Utility stops responding whenever you extract an archive.

Comment: didn;t work for me but @CraftyThumber worked

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: registred on this site to give you a PLUS for this

Comment: Doesn't work for me, on 10.8.2

Comment: I had to restart after following this step for it to take effect in 10.10

Comment: Worked immediately on Big Sur 11.2.3.

Answer (score 7):

I had to delete the lockfile also:

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist.lockfile
```

and then restarting the finder (or you can reboot):

```
killall Finder
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Running `sudo killall -KILL appleeventsd` didn't work for me. Simply deleting my Finder preferences did, though.

Comment: Worked for me too!  However, it undid the update to show hidden files that I'd done minutes earlier: http://www.mikesel.info/show-hidden-files-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/

Comment: (But redoing that update to show hidden files didn't provoke the show in finder problem again.  The first time I did the update it didn't "take", probably because the preferences file was already partly corrupted -- had to do the update twice.)

Answer (score 1):

In Yosemite 10.10.2, this is what I did to fix it:

open a new Terminal window and run this command

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

Then restart Finder with

```
killall Finder
```

Open a new Finder window with right click Finder icon -> New Finder window (because the bug prevents the normal left click action), press Shift + Cmd + G (Go to) and paste

```
~/Library/Preferences
```

Delete

- **com.apple.finder.plist**
- **com.apple.dock.plist**
- **com.apple.systemuiserver.plist**

Leave the Finder window open (I don´t know if it is necessary, but that´s what I did) Then switch to Terminal and paste

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
```

Restart Finder again

```
killall Finder
```

and finally

```
sudo killall -KILL appleeventsd
```

Restart your Mac, and chances are that everything is back to normal. Just remember that deleting the Finder preferences removes any custom views/side bar preferences, so just go through Finder -> Preferences again and fix things the way you like it.